# Computing the index of a singular point of a vector field

Tags: riemannian-geometry, vector-analysis

I'm struggling to understand how to easily compute the index of a singular point of a general vector field.

For example with the following:

[image: index of a vector field]

I have solutions which say "in each quadrant the angle turns by $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ so the total turning angle is $6\pi$, thus the index is 3". But I really don't see at all how the angle turns by $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ in each quadrant.

Answer (score 8):

Visually, draw a small circle around the singular point (where *small* means *enclosing only one singular point*). Traverse the circle once counterclockwise, counting how many times the field rotates relative to any convenient constant field (e.g., the rightward-pointing field, in green). The signed number of turns (positive for counterclockwise, negative for clockwise) is the index.

The fields shown have index $3$ and $-3$, respectively.

[image: Vector fields of index 3 and -3]

Comment: +1 Great explanation.