# Index of a linear map always zero?

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

Consider $A:  \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ a linear map. I'm interested in computing the index of the $A$ at the origin. The book that I'm studying defines the degree of a function $f: M \rightarrow N$ (where $M$ and $N$ are manifolds) at a point $y$ $\in$ $N$ (if $y$ is a regular point) as:
\begin{eqnarray}
\text{deg}(f;y) = \sum_{x \in f^{-1}(y)} \text{sgn}(df_x) 
\end{eqnarray}

where, 
$$\text{sgn}(df_x) =  \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
1\mbox{, if $df_x$ preserve orientation}\\
\\-1\mbox{, otherwise}\\
\end{array}
\right.$$

With little effort we can demonstrate that for any other regular point $z$ $\in$ $N$, $\text{deg}(f;y) =\text{deg}(f;z) $. So we can define $\text{deg}(f)$ without a point dependence.

We define the index of the vector field $X: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ (with an isolated zero $x_0$) as the degree of the function

$$Y(x) = \frac{X(x)}{\vert X(x)\vert}.$$

Now, I want to calculate the index of the map $X(x,y) = (y,x)$, using the definition. Consequently, I define

$$Y(x,y) = \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}},\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \right)$$

The curious thing occurring here is that $\det Y(x) = 0$ for every $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$ $\Rightarrow$ $\text{Ind}(X,0) = \text{deg}(Y) = 0$, (because  $\det Y(x) = 0$ for every $x$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R}^2$). Strangely if I do the same calculation for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, I get the same result. I know I made a big mistake somewhere, but I can't see where (because I know of the existence of a theorem that says $\text{Ind}(A,0) = \pm 1$, if $A$ has just eigenvalues with real part different of zero).

Can anyone help me to understand how to calculate the index of a vector field?

Comment: You need to view $Y$ as a mapping from the $(n-1)$-sphere to itself. For your last question, perhaps [Computing the index of a singular point of a vector field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2258912).